# Java, read from a String into an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a string with this content `12345`.

What's the best way to read these individual numbers into an ArrayList of integers?  like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
String data = getData();
this.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    int pt = Integer.parseInt(data.valueOf(i));
    this.points.add(new Integer(pt));
}
```

The problem is that I get `[(0),(1),(2),...]` instead of the numbers required.

Comment: Lookup what `String.valueOf` does - it does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work and keep your memory allocation to a minimum. Note that you need to make sure that only numerical values are present on data.

```
String data = getData();
this.points = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //if this is a field you should use points.clear() instead.

for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
  this.points.add(Characacter.getNumericValue(data.charAt(i)));
}
```

Your problem was that you were trying to use the [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method on the index, which will essentially return the value of i in every iteration

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `charAt(i)` method, `valueOf(i)` returns you the String value of i and not the i char

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.charAt` to get the corresponding character as `char` from the position. To add it to the list you need to convert to `int`.

```
String data = getData();
this.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    this.points.add(Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(i)));
}
```

Comment: In this case I get strange numbers like [40, 40, 48, 41, 40, 50, 41, 41]

Comment: This will return the ASCII values. Use `Character.getNumericValue` to return the numeric values.

Comment: Since you reopened your answer and fixed it I will remove mine, because its the same

Comment: @Sednus: Why? There are so many questions that have similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` will take the whole number; you want to take it digit-by-digit. For this, use `Character.getNumericValue` instead.

```
String data = getData();
this.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    int pt = Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(i));
    this.points.add(new Integer(pt));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have actual numbers? If you have a string like "123??5", the result will be [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, 5].

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The string is '12345'.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I tried this myself, with the sample string "12345", and printing `pt` followed by a space every time. I got "1 2 3 4 5 ".

Comment: Though actually, this will handle some Unicode. For example, u216C, the Roman numeral for fifty, will correctly be returned as 50.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data.charAt()` instead of  `valueOf`. So your code should look something like:

```
        String data = getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            int pt = Integer.parseInt(data.valueOf(data.charAt(i)));
            this.points.add(new Integer(pt));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.points.get(i));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String data = getData();
this.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    this.points.add(Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i) + ""));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You get all the integers like this:

```
String data = "254980";
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    list.add(new Integer(data.substring(i,i+1)));
}
```

Test:

```
for (Integer integer : list) {
    System.out.print(integer);
}
```

prints

```
2 
5 
4 
9 
8 
0
```

Comment: This solution wastes memory by creating new instances of strings with the substring method

Comment: The suggestion is not to use `substring` method inside a loop.  Each iteration of the loop requires a full re-scan of the entire string.